How to use Spring Repository on an Entity with PK that is also FK through @MapsId?
I'm trying to develop a simple API using Spring Boot v3.2.5 and Jakarta Persistence (which replaces javax.persistence).
I have a UserEntity with its own ID and a CandidateEntity with the ID mapped as OneToOne to the UserEntity so in the DB table of the CandidateEntity, its PK is also a FK referencing UserEntity:

BaseEntity.class:

@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @JsonSerialize
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
    public ZonedDateTime createdDate;

    @JsonSerialize
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    public ZonedDateTime updatedDate;
}


UserEntity.class:

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Users")
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    // Other fields

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userId")
    private CandidateEntity candidate;

    // Other fields
}


CandidateEntity.class:

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Candidates")
public class CandidateEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private UserEntity userId;

    // Other fields
}

This works as is and creates the desired DB tables and columns. Now I proceed to create a repository for each of the entities I have, including the CandidateEntity:

CandidateEntityRepository.class:

public interface CandidateEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<CandidateEntity, UserEntity> {

}

Re-running the project yields this error message now:
[  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'welcomePageHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'welcomePageHandlerMapping' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSchemaConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jsonSchemaConverter' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'associationLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'associationLinks' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceMappings' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'candidateEntityRepository' defined in com.example.simplevotingapi.repository.CandidateEntityRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: This class [class com.example.simplevotingapi.entity.CandidateEntity] does not define an IdClass

Adding @IdClass(UserEntity.class) to the CandidateEntity gets me the same error message, as if I don't have it.
Removing the repository works. I still need to have a repository to manage the candidates independent of the users.

build.gradle:

plugins {
    id 'idea'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
    id 'org.hibernate.orm' version '6.5.1.Final'
    id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.10.1'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct.extensions.spring:mapstruct-spring-annotations:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct.extensions.spring:mapstruct-spring-extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'io.github.linpeilie:mapstruct-plus-spring-boot-starter:1.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'io.github.linpeilie:mapstruct-plus-processor:1.4.0'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

So the relationship is ok in the way I envisioned it:

The problem comes when trying to define a Repository Interface on the owning side of the relationship.

For some reason, I managed to fix it by adding a separate ID field to the class. It doesn't create a new table column so the outcome is exactly how I wanted it, but reading the code is a bit weird now, having that extra field that doesn't have an equivalent in the DB.

DB Diagram:


CandidateEntityRepository.class:


@Repository
public interface CandidateEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<CandidateEntity, UserEntity>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<CandidateEntity> {

}


UserEntity.class:

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Users")
@AutoMapper(target = User.class, cycleAvoiding = true)
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    // Other fields

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userId")
    private CandidateEntity candidate;

    // Other fields

}


CandidateEntity.class:

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Candidates")
@AutoMapper(target = Candidate.class, cycleAvoiding = true)
public class CandidateEntity implements Serializable {

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @AutoMapping(source = "userId", target = "user")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private UserEntity userId;

    @Id
    private Long id; // This line made things work

    // Other fields
}

If anyone has an explanation for this, I'd be happy to hear about it.

@Entity
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FeedLike {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FeedLikeEmbedded feedLikeEmbedded;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("feedId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "feed_id")
    private Feed feed;
}

@Getter
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class FeedLikeEmbedded implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;


    @Column(name = "feed_id")
    private Long feedId;
}

public interface FeedLikeRepository extends JpaRepository<FeedLike, FeedLikeEmbedded> {
}

It can be used like this. As Another way, use @IdClass

This is for ManyToOne. I already implemented this in another entity. My use case is for OneToOne.
